# collaborative payment system

Tags: ios

How can I approach the idea of building a collaborative payment system? I've built a iOS chat app using Firebase and I'd like to add the functionality of allowing the members of a chat group to contribute an x amount of money where this money can later be utilized by the group admin.

For example, Alice creates a chat group for "Bob's birthday" and adds John and Kareem. They all want to pitch in to buy Bob a gift. John, Kareem and Alice all add $10 each through the "add money" button. Alice takes the $30 and buys the gift.

I've looked into PayPal and Stripe but they all seem to point towards 1-to-1 payments. How can I go about solving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has a collaborative payments platform called [Connect](https://stripe.com/gb/connect/use-cases) which seems what you're looking for. Failing that, you'd need some kind of white label system like [PayByGroup](https://www.paybygroup.com/) (unknown what their fees are) or another middle-man payment scheme where you can hold payments and redistribute them using an API, like [LiqPay](https://www.liqpay.ua/en) or [Skrill](https://www.skrill.com/en/).